# Manifolds with nonpositive radial curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

How can one construct examples of Riemannian manifolds which have nonpositive radial curvature about some point, but are not nonpositively curved everywhere? (I presume that they exist, but  do not know for sure.) The question may be formulated precisely as follows.

A (complete) Riemannian manifold $M$ has a *pole* at a point $p$, provided that the exponential map $exp_p \colon T_p M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism. The *radial curvatures* of $M$ (with respect to $p$) are the sectional curvatures with respect to the planes tangent to geodesics emanating from $p$. If all the radial curvatures are nonpositive, then how can $M$ have any positive curvature?

It is easy to show that such examples cannot be constructed by means of a warped product metric on $S^{n-1}\times[0,\infty)$. So $M$ cannot be too symmetric with respect to $p$. I would be particularly interested in $3$-dimensional examples.

Comment: If $exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism between the whole $T_pM$ and $M$, then $M$ must be diffeomorphic to  some standard Euclidean space. Is that really what you want? I suppose not since you are proposing a non-trivial product space as a non-example.

Comment: @Zerox: Yes, of course $M$ is diffeomorphic to $R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $M$ is three-dimenional and $\exp_p\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to M$ is a diffeomorphism.
Let $g_r$ be the Riemannian metric induced on $\mathbb{S}^{2}$ by the map $x\mapsto \exp_p(r\cdot x)$.

Note that $M$ has negative radial curvature if $g_r$ grows fast, say if $\tfrac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}g_r>g_r$.
But it gives absolutely no conditions on the shape of $(\mathbb{S}^{2},g_r)$ for large $r$.
So you can choose $(\mathbb{S}^{2},g_r)$ to be very positively curved at some point; say bigger than $(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial r}g_r(V,V)/g_r(V,V))^2$ for any tangent vector $V$.
Applying Gauss formula, you get that the sectional curvature in the direction tangent to the sphere is positive.